# mask or delete or remove missing data

Tags: python, nan, mask

I tried to plot a list p,

```
[[180],
 [180],
 [179],
 [179],
 [179],
 [178],
 [178],
 [177],
 [177],
 [176],
 [176],
 [175],
 [175],
 [174],
 [174],
 [173],
 [172],
 [172],
 [171],
 [171],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 []]
```

How can I get ride of the empty element. I just checked that python doesn't consider the empty elements as np.nan. I also tried code `ma.masked_invalid(p)`, but it didn't work either. I tried to make a loop and delete the empty element but I failed again.

Incidentally, I don't want to use df.DataFrame to plot my graph, because it cannot get exact what I want.

Comment: my_list = [element for element in my_initial_list if element ] ?

Comment: `list(filter(None, my_list))`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter this pretty easily by using the idea that Python interprets empty lists as "falsey"

```
>>> lst = [[1],[2],[],[],[]]
>>> filtered_lst = [elem for elem in lst if elem]
>>> filtered_lst
[[1], [2]]
```

This is a conditional list comprehension and uses the following format:

```
[f(a) for a in some_list if condition]
```

In this application `f(a)` is just reproducing `a` and condition determines if `a` is non-empty

Comment: Thx a lot! I will try it.